# Property 'imageUrl' of object ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_39_QML_108(0x1934a60) is not a function

Tags: qt, function, qml

I am trying to use the the `imageUrl` function in the QML code listed below but I get the following error: `Property 'imageUrl' of object ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_39_QML_108(0x1934a60) is not a function`.

Here is my QML code (note the comments):

```
ApplicationWindow {

    id:window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Open Picture")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: fileDialoge.open()
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    //this is my function
    function imageUrl(text)
    {
        console.log("Url: " + text);
    }

    // the user browse image from here
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialoge
        nameFilters: [ "Image files (*.png *.jpg)", "All files (*)" ]
        selectedNameFilter: "Image files (*.png *.jpg)"
        selectMultiple: true
    }
    Button {
        text: "Open"
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onClicked: fileDialoge.open()
    }

    // and I want the function to be called here
    Button {
        x: 136
        text: "Send"
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 0
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        onClicked: window.imageUrl(FileDialog.fileUrl)
    }
}
```

Comment: just call `imageUrl(FileDialog.fileUrl)` without `window.` at the beginning

Comment: @albemala, with 'window.' (i.e. `window.imageUrl(FileDialog.fileUrl)` should work as well, right?

Comment: @Ema, I can't recreate the error when using the example code.  The `imageUrL` is called and the message is written to the console without a problem when I run your example.

Comment: thank you all for replies , i don't know why it gives me that error
TypeError: Property 'imageUrl' of object ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_105_QML_108(0x250b390) is not a function